# points2one plugin subsitute for QGIS 3.4.4 version

Tags: qgis-plugins

Points2one plugin is not compatible with QGIS 3.4.4. It's quite useful for our works related to forestry. Is there any other substitute plugin or new upgrade version of points2one plugin?